# How to put watermark in some segment .ts without transcoding full video

Tags: ffmpeg, watermark, hls

I'm using the command below to create an HLS playlist:

```
ffmpeg -i "Full.mp4" -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -vcodec libx264 -crf 22 -preset medium -c:a copy -filter:v:0 scale=w=480:h=360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -maxrate:v:0 600k -b:a:0 64k -filter:v:1 scale=w=640:h=480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -maxrate:v:1 800k -b:a:1 128k -filter:v:2 scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -maxrate:v:2 1000k -b:a:2 128k -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0,name:360p v:1,a:1,name:480p v:2,a:2,name:720p" -f hls -hls_playlist_type vod -hls_flags independent_segments -master_pl_name "playlist.m3u8" "%v.m3u8"
```

After, I need to put a dynamic watermark in some segments, for this I'm using the command:

```
ffmpeg -i "360p0.ts" -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=10:10:enable=between(t\,0\,30)" -preset ultrafast -c:v libx264 -maxrate 600k -codec:a copy "360p0-watermark.ts"
```

But when I try to play the video, the player crashes when playing a segment without a watermark and resumes when it finds the next segment with a watermark.

I cannot add the watermark on the first conversion because the watermark is dynamic, so I should add the watermark only when the user plays the video.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?